# Why are two Doubles being concatenated instead of added

Tags: java, android

when I try to add two variables of double type, they are concatenated instead of being added together. what could I be missing here, both the Strings and the answer variables are class level variables so that they can be changed by the on create method and various mathmatical operation methods. should I move somethings out of the onCreate method?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.hernandez.simplecalculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //numbers
     String num1 = "0";
     String num2 = "0";


    double answer;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView text = findViewById(R.id.answer);

        text.setText("");

        //controls
        RadioButton rbAdd = findViewById(R.id.radioButtonAdd);
        RadioButton rbSub = findViewById(R.id.radioButtonSubtract);
        RadioButton rbMult = findViewById(R.id.radioButtonMultiply);
        RadioButton rbDiv= findViewById(R.id.radioButtonDivide);
        Button btnCalcualate = findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);

        //number buttons
        Button btn1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button btn2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button btn3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Button btn4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Button btn5 = findViewById(R.id.button5);
        Button btn6 = findViewById(R.id.button6);
        Button btn7 = findViewById(R.id.button7);
        Button btn8 = findViewById(R.id.button8);
        Button btn9 = findViewById(R.id.button9);
        Button btn0 = findViewById(R.id.button0);



            //function buttons
            rbAdd.setOnClickListener(view -> text.append(" + "));
            rbSub.setOnClickListener(view -> text.append(" - "));
            rbMult.setOnClickListener(view -> text.append(" x "));
            rbDiv.setOnClickListener(view -> text.append(" / "));

        if(!rbAdd.isChecked() || !rbSub.isChecked() || !rbDiv.isChecked() || !rbMult.isChecked()) {
            //number buttons
            btn0.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                text.append("0");
                num1 += "0";
            });
            btn1.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                text.append("1");
                num1 += "1";
            });
            btn2.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                text.append("2");
                num1 += "2";
            });
            btn3.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                text.append("3");
                num1 += "3";
            });
            btn4.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                text.append("4");
                num1 += "4";
            });
            btn5.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                text.append("5");
                num1 += "5";
            });
            btn6.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                text.append("6");
                num1 += "6";
            });
            btn7.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                text.append("7");
                num1 += "7";
            });
            btn8.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                text.append("8");
                num1 += "8";
            });
            btn9.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                text.append("9");
                num1 += "9";
            });
        }
        else if (rbAdd.isChecked() || rbSub.isChecked() || rbDiv.isChecked() || rbMult.isChecked()){
            btn0.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                text.append("0");
                num2 += "0";
            });
            btn1.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                text.append("1");
                num2 += "1";
            });
            btn2.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                text.append("2");
                num2 += "2";
            });
            btn3.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                text.append("3");
                num2 += "3";
            });
            btn4.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                text.append("4");
                num2 += "4";
            });
            btn5.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                text.append("5");
                num2 += "5";
            });
            btn6.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                text.append("6");
                num2 += "6";
            });
            btn7.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                text.append("7");
                num2 += "7";
            });
            btn8.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                text.append("8");
                num2 += "8";
            });
            btn9.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                text.append("9");
                num2 += "9";
            });
        }

        btnCalcualate.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            // which button is checked?
            if (rbAdd.isChecked()) {
                doAdd();
            } else if (rbSub.isChecked()) {
                doSubtract();
            } else if (rbMult.isChecked()){
                doMultiply();
            }else if(rbDiv.isChecked()){
                doDivide();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please check one option.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            text.setText(Double.toString(answer));
        });

    }

    public void doAdd(){
        try{
            double n1 = new Double(num1).doubleValue();
            double n2 = new Double(num2).doubleValue();
            answer = (n1 + n2);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }


    }
    public void doSubtract(){
        try{
            answer = Double.parseDouble(num1) - Double.parseDouble(num2);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
    public void doMultiply(){
        try{
            answer = Double.parseDouble(num1) * Double.parseDouble(num2);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
    public void doDivide() {
        try {
            answer = Double.parseDouble(num1) / Double.parseDouble(num2);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }

    }
}
```

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/darkgrey"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="127dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:text="5"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.286" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_width="127dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.478" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="127dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:text="3"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.947"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.382" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="127dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:text="2"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.382" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="127dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:text="7"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.052"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.19" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="127dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.052"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.382" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="127dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:text="9"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.94"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.19" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="127dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:text="6"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.94"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.286" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="127dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:text="8"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.19" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="127dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:text="4"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.052"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.286" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answer"
        android:layout_width="413dp"
        android:layout_height="116dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="56sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="359dp"
        android:layout_height="156dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.728">


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonAdd"
            android:layout_width="98dp"
            android:layout_height="129dp"
            android:text="+"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="100dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonDivide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="/"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="100dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonSubtract"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="100dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonMultiply"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="X"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="100dp" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCalculate"
        android:layout_width="352dp"
        android:layout_height="112dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
        android:text="Calculate"
        android:textSize="28dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.559"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.974" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried to convert from String to double in different ways but it still concatenated the values instead of adding them.

here is the output
[equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3g5t1.jpg)
[sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHaM5.jpg)

Comment: if you are going to use a primitive value of double, why use new Double().doubleValue()? Use Double.parseDouble() to directly get a primitive

Comment: can you step through with a debugger/print out the values of n1 and n2 in order to see if they are both what you expect inside the doAdd() method?

Comment: Way too much code for a simple question. Contrive example code when posting here.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in how you decide whether the radio buttons for add/sub/mul/div are checked or not. Because this check is placed in `onCreate`, it will only be executed once. This means that the same set of click listeners will be executed every time, resulting in the numeric value always being concatenated to the `num1` string.

So when you press the button "7" you will have `num1 = "07"`, then when you press the button "+", it will append " + " to your `text` (`TextView`) and then when you press the button "7" again, you will have `num1 = "077"`. Converting a `String` with value `"077"` to a `double`/`Double` will result in the value `77.0`.

My suggestion would be to keep just one set of click listeners and do the radio button check inside them. If you do that you can even move all the logic to a separate function (method in your class).

Create a method before or after your `onCreate` method:

```java
// I specifically opted for int instead of String as the input parameter,
// use types that best restrict valid input values to reduce the chance for bugs (here an enum for 0-9 would be even safer)
private void appendDigit(int digit) {
    String digitText = digit.toString();
    text.append(digitText);
    if (rbAdd.isChecked() || rbSub.isChecked() || rbDiv.isChecked() || rbMult.isChecked()) {
        num2 += digitText;
    } else {
        num1 += digitText;
    }
}
```

Then in your `onCreate` method replace the whole `if/else if` part with just a single set of click handlers and call this new method in each one of them.

```java
    btn0.setOnClickListener(view -> { appendDigit(0); });
    btn1.setOnClickListener(view -> { appendDigit(1); });
    btn2.setOnClickListener(view -> { appendDigit(2); });
    btn3.setOnClickListener(view -> { appendDigit(3); });
    btn4.setOnClickListener(view -> { appendDigit(4); });
    btn5.setOnClickListener(view -> { appendDigit(5); });
    btn6.setOnClickListener(view -> { appendDigit(6); });
    btn7.setOnClickListener(view -> { appendDigit(7); });
    btn8.setOnClickListener(view -> { appendDigit(8); });
    btn9.setOnClickListener(view -> { appendDigit(9); });
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code only num1 variable is updating always and num2 is never getting updated and always been as empty string as you have set it on top.
I have updated your activity file where your calculator program is working fine. You can refer the same.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//numbers
String num1 = "0";
String num2 = "0";
double answer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_java);

    TextView text = findViewById(R.id.answer);

    text.setText("");

    //controls
    RadioButton rbAdd = findViewById(R.id.radioButtonAdd);
    RadioButton rbSub = findViewById(R.id.radioButtonSubtract);
    RadioButton rbMult = findViewById(R.id.radioButtonMultiply);
    RadioButton rbDiv = findViewById(R.id.radioButtonDivide);
    Button btnCalcualate = findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);

    //number buttons
    Button btn1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button btn2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button btn3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button btn4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
    Button btn5 = findViewById(R.id.button5);
    Button btn6 = findViewById(R.id.button6);
    Button btn7 = findViewById(R.id.button7);
    Button btn8 = findViewById(R.id.button8);
    Button btn9 = findViewById(R.id.button9);
    Button btn0 = findViewById(R.id.button0);


    //function buttons
    rbAdd.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        rbAdd.setChecked(true);
        text.append(" + ");
    });
    rbSub.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        rbSub.setChecked(true);
        text.append(" - ");
    });
    rbMult.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        rbMult.setChecked(true);
        text.append(" x ");
    });
    rbDiv.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        rbDiv.setChecked(true);
        text.append(" / ");
    });


    //number buttons
    btn0.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        text.append("0");
        if (text.getText().toString().contains("+") || text.getText().toString().contains("-") || text.getText().toString().contains("x") || text.getText().toString().contains("/"))
            num2 += "0";
        else
            num1 += "0";
    });
    btn1.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        text.append("1");
        if (text.getText().toString().contains("+") || text.getText().toString().contains("-") || text.getText().toString().contains("x") || text.getText().toString().contains("/"))
            num2 += "1";
        else
            num1 += "1";
    });
    btn2.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        text.append("2");
        if (text.getText().toString().contains("+") || text.getText().toString().contains("-") || text.getText().toString().contains("x") || text.getText().toString().contains("/"))
            num2 += "2";
        else
            num1 += "2";
    });
    btn3.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        text.append("3");
        if (text.getText().toString().contains("+") || text.getText().toString().contains("-") || text.getText().toString().contains("x") || text.getText().toString().contains("/"))
            num2 += "3";
        else
            num1 += "3";
    });
    btn4.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        text.append("4");
        if (text.getText().toString().contains("+") || text.getText().toString().contains("-") || text.getText().toString().contains("x") || text.getText().toString().contains("/"))
            num2 += "4";
        else
            num1 += "4";
    });
    btn5.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        text.append("5");
        if (text.getText().toString().contains("+") || text.getText().toString().contains("-") || text.getText().toString().contains("x") || text.getText().toString().contains("/"))
            num2 += "5";
        else
            num1 += "5";
    });
    btn6.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        text.append("6");
        if (text.getText().toString().contains("+") || text.getText().toString().contains("-") || text.getText().toString().contains("x") || text.getText().toString().contains("/"))
            num2 += "6";
        else
            num1 += "6";
    });
    btn7.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        text.append("7");
        if (text.getText().toString().contains("+") || text.getText().toString().contains("-") || text.getText().toString().contains("x") || text.getText().toString().contains("/"))
            num2 += "7";
        else
            num1 += "7";
    });
    btn8.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        text.append("8");
        if (text.getText().toString().contains("+") || text.getText().toString().contains("-") || text.getText().toString().contains("x") || text.getText().toString().contains("/"))
            num2 += "8";
        else
            num1 += "8";
    });
    btn9.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        text.append("9");
        if (text.getText().toString().contains("+") || text.getText().toString().contains("-") || text.getText().toString().contains("x") || text.getText().toString().contains("/"))
            num2 += "9";
        else
            num1 += "9";
    });

    btnCalcualate.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        // which button is checked?
        if (rbAdd.isChecked()) {
            doAdd();
        } else if (rbSub.isChecked()) {
            doSubtract();
        } else if (rbMult.isChecked()) {
            doMultiply();
        } else if (rbDiv.isChecked()) {
            doDivide();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivityJava.this, "Please check one option.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        num2 = "";
        num1 = answer + "";
        text.setText(Double.toString(answer));
    });
}

public void doAdd() {
    try {
        double n1 = Double.parseDouble(num1);
        double n2 = Double.parseDouble(num2);
        answer = (n1 + n2);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void doSubtract() {
    try {
        answer = Double.parseDouble(num1) - Double.parseDouble(num2);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void doMultiply() {
    try {
        answer = Double.parseDouble(num1) * Double.parseDouble(num2);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void doDivide() {
    try {
        answer = Double.parseDouble(num1) / Double.parseDouble(num2);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }
}}
```

This works for me, let me know if this works for you or not.